# How can i get the button "roll" in the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the button roll in my code to be on top of the video in the center but im not quite sure how i can do that?
I have tried to make the button as a class e.g. class="button" and then i tried to make it center but it just does not work.
I have not going anything in css related to the button everything is done within the script.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>

var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "How can we become more self-organised in the next sprint?";
r_text[1] = "How can we improve our productivity, increase our velocity?";
r_text[2] = "How can we get better in Transparency and Visibility of issues and challenges?";
r_text[3] = "How can our PO help us, to focus more on the sprint goal?";
r_text[4] = "How can our SM help us improve our delivery?";
r_text[5] = "How can we be more T-shaped in the next sprint?";
r_text[6] = "How should we celebrate our successes more?";
r_text[7] = "How can we reduce our cycle times?";
r_text[8] = "How can we make our daily scrum more effective?";
r_text[9] = "How can we improve our delivery flow by applying WIP Limit?";
r_text[10] = "How can we improve our collaboration?";
r_text[11] = "How can I help someone else in the next sprint?";
r_text[12] = "How can we improve our Sprint planning event?";
r_text[13] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Courage more?";
r_text[14] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Respect more?";
r_text[15] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Focus more?";
r_text[16] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Commitment more?";
r_text[17] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Openness more?";
r_text[18] = "How can we make Sprint Review more effective?";
r_text[19] = "How can I help PO breakdown user stories better?";
r_text[20] = "How can we improve user story refinement?";
r_text[21] = "How did you overcome a dfficult situation/chalenge?";
r_text[22] = "How can we be more confident about our delivery?";
r_text[23] = "How well do you communicate with others?";
r_text[24] = "How well the team communicates with each other?";


var talk = new Array();
talk[0] = "Talk about issues in our Processes";
talk[1] = "Talk about issues in the Team behaviour";
talk[2] = "Talk about what you want your team to do more";
talk[3] = "Talk about what you want the team to stop doing";
talk[4] = "Talk about what you want the team to start doing";
talk[5] = "Tell us about something that helped you during the sprint to achieve work";
talk[6] = "Talk about something you learnt during the  previous sprint";
talk[7] = "Talk about your sprint experience through a sport's game?";
talk[8] = "Talk about your worst time during the sprint?";
talk[9] = "Talk about the biggest success during the sprint?";
talk[10] = "Talk about he major issue you faced during the sprint?";
talk[11] = "Talk about a most recent problem and how did you overcome it?";
talk[12] = "Talk about something that you feared during sprint planning however it was not mentioned at that time?";
talk[13] = "Talk about someone in the team you inspire from and why? Don’t mention the name";


var what = new Array();
what[0] = "What can Scrum Master to improve our Scrum Events?";
what[1] = "What made you feel happy?";
what[2] = "What made you feel unhappy?";
what[3] = "What was your key observations?";
what[4] = "What minor issues that slowed you down";
what[5] = "What can we change to make the biggest leap ahead?";
what[6] = "What did you see happening by someone you think everyone should try?";
what[7] = "What advise would you give to your team members? And why?";
what[8] = "What has been the biggest challenge so far?";
what[9] = "Which problems came up most frequently?";
what[10] = "What has been the most difficult situation in the sprint?";
what[11] = "What obstacles do you anticipate and how you think that can be addressed?";
what[12] = "What can we do to improve our Sprint planning event?";
what[13] = "What would you do differently in the next Sprint?";
what[14] = "What would you like to avoid in the next Sprint?";
what[15] = "What can we do to make our Scrum events more fun?";
what[16] = "What can we do to get full trust of our key stakeholders?";
what[17] = "What support do we need from our PO?";
what[18] = "What support do we need from our SM?";
what[19] = "What support do we need from our Stakeholders? Sponsrs/External…";
what[20] = "Describe the most difficult challenge team faced? What could have been done to avoid/fix it?";
what[21] = "What do you wish you could change in the way of working?";
what[22] = "What support do you need to achieve your sprint goal?";
what[23] = "What areas of your team WOW would you like to improve/change?";
what[24] = "What routinely gets in your way?";
what[25] = "What would you like your PO to do more and why?";
what[26] = "What would you like your SM to do less and why?";


var morefun = new Array();
morefun[0] = "Describe your feeling by naming a Movie. Explain";
morefun[1] = "Describe your feeling by singing a Song. Explain";
morefun[2] = "Describe your feeling by hands/body gestures.";
morefun[3] = "Describe your sprint experience by telling a story?";
morefun[4] = "Who's someone you admire in the team?";
morefun[5] = "What is your favorite quotes?";
morefun[6] = "Who had the most influence on you growing up?";
morefun[7] = "What advise can you give us?";
morefun[8] = "If you could go back in time, what would you like to change? Work or Life";
morefun[9] = "Show your best dance moves?";
morefun[10] = "Draw an emoji to show how you feel about the sprint";
morefun[11] = "How would you have handled Brexit?";
morefun[12] = "If you would become the Prime Minister what would be your top agenda items?";
morefun[13] = "Do an animal impression (please don’t tell)";
morefun[14] = "Do an impression of a Cartoon character (please don’t tell)";
morefun[15] = "If you had a 30 hours a day, how would you use the extra time?";
morefun[16] = "If you could swap your role with another team member, who would it be?";
morefun[17] = "Do a Bhangra dance?";
morefun[18] = "Ask anyone in the team to perform an act? Movie character, cartoon character etc…";
morefun[19] = "Stand on one leg and jump 5 times, or ask your PO to do this act?";
morefun[20] = "Ask your SM or PO to perform a celebration move, or could decide to do it yourself.";


var showshare = new Array();
showshare[0] = "Share your most recent learning experience?";
showshare[1] = "Share any productivity improvement tip with the team?";
showshare[2] = "Share your best moment during the Sprint and why?";
showshare[3] = "if you could change one thing about yourself what would you choose?";
showshare[4] = "If you could eliminate one thing from your daily routine what whould it be?";
showshare[5] = "If you could become an expert in any area instantly, what would it be?";
showshare[6] = "Share a tip to help others improve their ways of working?";


var goingtodo = new Array();
goingtodo[0] = "Do I/we understand the Product Vision? Team and I";
goingtodo[1] = "Do I/we understand the Sprint Goal? Why, Value, Benefits. Team and I";
goingtodo[2] = "Do I/we communicate well within the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[3] = "Do I/we communicate well outside the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[4] = "Do I/we collaborate with team and outside team? Team and I";
goingtodo[5] = "Do I/we openly raise issues and challenges? Team and I";
goingtodo[6] = "Do I/we openly talk about impediments?";
goingtodo[7] = "Do we ask each other for help and support?";



var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-1.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return r_text[Math.floor(r_text.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-2.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return what[Math.floor(what.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-3.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return talk[Math.floor(talk.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-4.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return morefun[Math.floor(morefun.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-5.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return showshare[Math.floor(showshare.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Red-dice.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return goingtodo[Math.floor(goingtodo.length*Math.random())];
    }
  }

];

var currentTimeout = null;
window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {
    let playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
    if (document.querySelector("iframe") !== null) {
      document.querySelector("iframe").remove();
    }
    let player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    let randomVideoUrl = videos[numberRand].url;
    player.setAttribute("width", "640");
    player.setAttribute("height", "390");
    player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
    currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text();
    }, 3000);
  }


  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);

  function startRoll() {
    let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    rollVideo(currentNumber);
  }
};





    </script>
</head>

<button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
<div id="random_player">
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant styles as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the button instead the div section, use align property

```
 <div align="center">    
        <button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you i will give this a go

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from the given problem please check the given solution, it would be good if you share the styles.

```css
body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <html>

<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/> -->
    <script>

var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "How can we become more self-organised in the next sprint?";
r_text[1] = "How can we improve our productivity, increase our velocity?";
r_text[2] = "How can we get better in Transparency and Visibility of issues and challenges?";
r_text[3] = "How can our PO help us, to focus more on the sprint goal?";
r_text[4] = "How can our SM help us improve our delivery?";
r_text[5] = "How can we be more T-shaped in the next sprint?";
r_text[6] = "How should we celebrate our successes more?";
r_text[7] = "How can we reduce our cycle times?";
r_text[8] = "How can we make our daily scrum more effective?";
r_text[9] = "How can we improve our delivery flow by applying WIP Limit?";
r_text[10] = "How can we improve our collaboration?";
r_text[11] = "How can I help someone else in the next sprint?";
r_text[12] = "How can we improve our Sprint planning event?";
r_text[13] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Courage more?";
r_text[14] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Respect more?";
r_text[15] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Focus more?";
r_text[16] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Commitment more?";
r_text[17] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Openness more?";
r_text[18] = "How can we make Sprint Review more effective?";
r_text[19] = "How can I help PO breakdown user stories better?";
r_text[20] = "How can we improve user story refinement?";
r_text[21] = "How did you overcome a dfficult situation/chalenge?";
r_text[22] = "How can we be more confident about our delivery?";
r_text[23] = "How well do you communicate with others?";
r_text[24] = "How well the team communicates with each other?";


var talk = new Array();
talk[0] = "Talk about issues in our Processes";
talk[1] = "Talk about issues in the Team behaviour";
talk[2] = "Talk about what you want your team to do more";
talk[3] = "Talk about what you want the team to stop doing";
talk[4] = "Talk about what you want the team to start doing";
talk[5] = "Tell us about something that helped you during the sprint to achieve work";
talk[6] = "Talk about something you learnt during the  previous sprint";
talk[7] = "Talk about your sprint experience through a sport's game?";
talk[8] = "Talk about your worst time during the sprint?";
talk[9] = "Talk about the biggest success during the sprint?";
talk[10] = "Talk about he major issue you faced during the sprint?";
talk[11] = "Talk about a most recent problem and how did you overcome it?";
talk[12] = "Talk about something that you feared during sprint planning however it was not mentioned at that time?";
talk[13] = "Talk about someone in the team you inspire from and why? Don’t mention the name";


var what = new Array();
what[0] = "What can Scrum Master to improve our Scrum Events?";
what[1] = "What made you feel happy?";
what[2] = "What made you feel unhappy?";
what[3] = "What was your key observations?";
what[4] = "What minor issues that slowed you down";
what[5] = "What can we change to make the biggest leap ahead?";
what[6] = "What did you see happening by someone you think everyone should try?";
what[7] = "What advise would you give to your team members? And why?";
what[8] = "What has been the biggest challenge so far?";
what[9] = "Which problems came up most frequently?";
what[10] = "What has been the most difficult situation in the sprint?";
what[11] = "What obstacles do you anticipate and how you think that can be addressed?";
what[12] = "What can we do to improve our Sprint planning event?";
what[13] = "What would you do differently in the next Sprint?";
what[14] = "What would you like to avoid in the next Sprint?";
what[15] = "What can we do to make our Scrum events more fun?";
what[16] = "What can we do to get full trust of our key stakeholders?";
what[17] = "What support do we need from our PO?";
what[18] = "What support do we need from our SM?";
what[19] = "What support do we need from our Stakeholders? Sponsrs/External…";
what[20] = "Describe the most difficult challenge team faced? What could have been done to avoid/fix it?";
what[21] = "What do you wish you could change in the way of working?";
what[22] = "What support do you need to achieve your sprint goal?";
what[23] = "What areas of your team WOW would you like to improve/change?";
what[24] = "What routinely gets in your way?";
what[25] = "What would you like your PO to do more and why?";
what[26] = "What would you like your SM to do less and why?";


var morefun = new Array();
morefun[0] = "Describe your feeling by naming a Movie. Explain";
morefun[1] = "Describe your feeling by singing a Song. Explain";
morefun[2] = "Describe your feeling by hands/body gestures.";
morefun[3] = "Describe your sprint experience by telling a story?";
morefun[4] = "Who's someone you admire in the team?";
morefun[5] = "What is your favorite quotes?";
morefun[6] = "Who had the most influence on you growing up?";
morefun[7] = "What advise can you give us?";
morefun[8] = "If you could go back in time, what would you like to change? Work or Life";
morefun[9] = "Show your best dance moves?";
morefun[10] = "Draw an emoji to show how you feel about the sprint";
morefun[11] = "How would you have handled Brexit?";
morefun[12] = "If you would become the Prime Minister what would be your top agenda items?";
morefun[13] = "Do an animal impression (please don’t tell)";
morefun[14] = "Do an impression of a Cartoon character (please don’t tell)";
morefun[15] = "If you had a 30 hours a day, how would you use the extra time?";
morefun[16] = "If you could swap your role with another team member, who would it be?";
morefun[17] = "Do a Bhangra dance?";
morefun[18] = "Ask anyone in the team to perform an act? Movie character, cartoon character etc…";
morefun[19] = "Stand on one leg and jump 5 times, or ask your PO to do this act?";
morefun[20] = "Ask your SM or PO to perform a celebration move, or could decide to do it yourself.";


var showshare = new Array();
showshare[0] = "Share your most recent learning experience?";
showshare[1] = "Share any productivity improvement tip with the team?";
showshare[2] = "Share your best moment during the Sprint and why?";
showshare[3] = "if you could change one thing about yourself what would you choose?";
showshare[4] = "If you could eliminate one thing from your daily routine what whould it be?";
showshare[5] = "If you could become an expert in any area instantly, what would it be?";
showshare[6] = "Share a tip to help others improve their ways of working?";


var goingtodo = new Array();
goingtodo[0] = "Do I/we understand the Product Vision? Team and I";
goingtodo[1] = "Do I/we understand the Sprint Goal? Why, Value, Benefits. Team and I";
goingtodo[2] = "Do I/we communicate well within the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[3] = "Do I/we communicate well outside the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[4] = "Do I/we collaborate with team and outside team? Team and I";
goingtodo[5] = "Do I/we openly raise issues and challenges? Team and I";
goingtodo[6] = "Do I/we openly talk about impediments?";
goingtodo[7] = "Do we ask each other for help and support?";



var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-1.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return r_text[Math.floor(r_text.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-2.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return what[Math.floor(what.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-3.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return talk[Math.floor(talk.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-4.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return morefun[Math.floor(morefun.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-5.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return showshare[Math.floor(showshare.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Red-dice.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return goingtodo[Math.floor(goingtodo.length*Math.random())];
    }
  }

];

var currentTimeout = null;
window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {
    let playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
    if (document.querySelector("iframe") !== null) {
      document.querySelector("iframe").remove();
    }
    let player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    let randomVideoUrl = videos[numberRand].url;
    player.setAttribute("width", "640");
    player.setAttribute("height", "390");
    player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
    currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text();
    }, 3000);
  }


  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);

  function startRoll() {
    let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    rollVideo(currentNumber);
  }
};





    </script>
</head>
    <div style="position: relative;width:100%;height:100%;background: yellow">
        <div style="position: absolute;top:50%;left:50%;">
            <button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="random_player">
      <div id="text"></div>
    </div>

</html>
```